# How can I use SQL to return a list of customers with both a home phone & cell phone, home phone only, cell phone only, and no phone?

Tags: sql, group-by

I hope I am making this more difficult than it really is. Here is my problem: I need to write a SQL query which will count up all the customers in CUSTOMER_TABLE that have a PHONE_TYPE of "home phone" and "cell phone" (i.e., these customers have two rows in the table) all the customers that only have "home phone" (these customers only have one row in the table) all the customers that only have "cell phone" (these customers also only have one row in the table) and all the customers that have neither PHONE_TYPE (these customers have at least one row in the table). Here is a brief example of how it should work:

Sample data in the CUSTOMER_ADDRESS table:

```
ACCOUNT_NO   PHONE_TYPE
----------   ----------
A            home phone
A            cell phone
B            home phone
C            home phone
D            cell phone
E            work phone
F            no phone
```

On paper, the query would return something like:

```
Phone types                           | Account Numbers
-------------------------------------------------------
Both "home phone" and "cell phone"    | A
-------------------------------------------------------
"home phone" only                     | B, C
-------------------------------------------------------
"cell phone" only                     | D
-------------------------------------------------------
Neither "home phone" nor "cell phone" | E, F
```

I don't believe a UNION will work. A rudimentary stab at creating the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT PHONE_TYPE, ACCOUNT_NO
FROM CUSTOMER_ADDRESS 
WHERE...help!!!!!! 
GROUP BY PHONE_TYPE, ACCOUNT_NO
ORDER BY PHONE_TYPE, ACCOUNT_NO
```

Thank you!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use WinSQL, which does not have a `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, I believe.

Comment: @JasonBodak WinSQL is just an interface to your database, what database does it connect to?

Comment: Hi. Sorry...not thinking. The DB is IBM Netezza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information at a per-customer level.  Here is one method, using MySQL syntax:

```
select phone_type, group_concat(account_no) as accounts
from (select ca.account_no,
             group_concat(distinct phone_type order by phone_type separator ' and ') as phone_types
      from customer_address ca
      group by ca.account_no
     ) ca
group by phone_type;
```

This is the basic query.  Most databases have a function similar to `group_concat()`.